# Pivot / Dcast using sparse matrix with character values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have following data frame-

**Data frame looks like this:**

```
id <- c(1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
col <- c("a","a","b","c","d","b","c","d","a","b")
val <- as.character(c("t1","x1","x2","x3","x4","y2","y3","y4","z1","z2"))
values <- data.frame(id,col,val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> values
   id col val
1   1   a  t1
2   2   a  x1
3   2   b  x2
4   2   c  x3
5   2   d  x4
6   3   b  y2
7   3   c  y3
8   3   d  y4
9   4   a  z1
10  4   b  z2
```

I am trying to pivot above data frame using `sparseMatrix()`  using below code

```
data = transform(values,id = as.factor(id),col = factor(col))
data.sparse = Matrix::sparseMatrix(as.integer(data$id), as.integer(data$col))
colnames(data.sparse) = levels(data$col)
rownames(data.sparse) = levels(data$id)
test <-  as.data.frame.matrix(data.sparse)
test <- 1 * test
```

I can use above method for numerical data.
But, I know sparseMatrix() doesn't support `x=as.character(val)` in `sparseMatrix()`

**Note- I can't use `data.table::dcast()` or `reshape::dcast()` because of long vector issue.**

Is there any other way to handle very large data pivoting in R?

Please look at desired output below:

```
> output
   id  a  b  c  d
1:  1 t1  0  0  0
2:  2 x1 x2 x3 x4
3:  3  0 y2 y3 y4
4:  4 z1 z2  0  0
```

Suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about `values <- tidyr::spread(values, col, val)`? And then you can replace nas with zeros.

Comment: @suchait I guess all those function will have long vectors not supported issue. That's why I specifically wanted to use sparseMatrix()

Comment: would it help if you split by id first to reduce the dimension?